# correct way of adding single line break in jquery variable

Tags: jquery

I want to include a single line break in a jquery variable but I am getting a syntax error with my operator:

```
var $answer = $("\n" + "<table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>" + "\n");
```

What is the correct way for me to be able to include a single line break before and after this table?

Comment: Maybe I'm not looking at this right, but can't you just add a <br /> before and after the <table>? Alternatively, I personally would use css for spacing.

Comment: use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Comment: I don't get a syntax error with your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using css for your styling, however this should be the answer you're looking for:

```
var $answer = $("<br /><table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table><br />");
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
var $answer = "<br/><table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody</table><br />";
```

Comment: And why it this different than the other answer ?

Comment: -1: Depends on what you're doing. You can't chain jQuery methods off a string as in your example. Ultimately if you plan to do anything like .find(), .appendTo(), etc - then you'll have to wrap it in $().